# Does fetch request in JS cache the response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

When querying using fetch in `js`, I get data on the site `/order/1` returns to me `{uri:'/me/order/1'}`, which means that I am the owner of this resource at this moment, my user id is 1, then I go to the site under the data of another user with id=2 and my token is different.

My code:

```js
  fetch(`${runtimeConfig.public.apiBase}/orders/${route.params.id}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.value}`
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    if (data && !data.uri) {
      order.value = data
    }
    if (data.uri) {
      getMyOrder(data.uri)
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error:", err);
  });
```

I execute the request `/order/1` and I get the result `{uri:'/me/order/1'}`, although the user has changed and I should get `{order_id:1, name: 'qwerty'}`, I checked, the token definitely belongs to another user. Everything works correctly in postman, I get the expected response, and in browsers I get what I think is a cached response

After the deletion request, I get this list:

```
[
  {order_id:2, name: 'asd'},
  {order_id:3, name: 'rew'},
  {order_id:0, name: ''}
]
```

In Postman, there is no third element at all, as it should be

Comment: I've tried it in different browsers, on different devices

Comment: The `cache` option isn't a header. Move it out to be a top-level property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#cache

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't help, it returns an already deleted resource to me in my request

Comment: Check the request headers using your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel and confirm the bearer token used in the request has actually changed.

Comment: @Phil I copy the token from the browser, paste it into Postman and it returns the correct result to me, but everything works quite strangely in the browser

Comment: Copied from the request headers via the _Network_ panel?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/kaxKwnU) I have such headers

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because it's unclear where `token.value` comes from or how it's updated when you change users (if at all). If you're absolutely sure that the token used in requests changes when you switch users, try clearing your browser cache. It may have cached a previous version of your app where the `cache` property was in the wrong place

Comment: I changed browsers, deleted the token from cookies, the token is definitely deleted when I log out of my account

Comment: `After the deletion request` ... what deletion request? Did I miss that in the code? try using `no-store` rather than `no-cache` - [read docs for the difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache)

Comment: Looks like your server should send a [`Vary: Authorization` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#vary) when serving different content to GET requests with the same URL. The client js shouldn't need to deal with this.